# I am passing data to another component , but when i am printing a data in another component it showing me null;

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I am fetching a covid 19 data from API in component named as covid_update
I am passing a data from api to another component named as Tables but when I am printing a console .log(props) in usestate of Tables then it showing no data.

I don't know where is error in code .
when I am printing  a incoming data in Tables component, I am getting this response in console
**{data: "{}"}**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../Home/Header/Header';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from '../Home/Header/Header';
import { Button, Card, Col, Container, Row, Spinner, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Chart from "react-google-charts";
import Trackers from './Trackers';
import Charts from './Charts';
import Tables from './Tables';
import Carousels from './Carousels';
import Axios from 'axios';
import './Covid_Update.css';


function Covid_Update() {

  const [state_data,set_state_data]=React.useState({});
  useEffect(() => {

    Axios.get("https://api.covid19india.org/data.json").then(function (val) {
    const res=val.data;
    set_state_data(res);
   
  })

  
  },[])


  return (
    <>
     { 
      state_data==null?<Container id="load"><center><Spinner animation="grow" variant="dark" size="100" /></center></Container>:<div>
      <Tables data={JSON.stringify(state_data)} />
      </div>
            }

    </>
  );
}
export default Covid_Update;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import Navbar from '../Home/Header/Header';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from '../Home/Header/Header';
import { Button, Card, Col, Container, Row, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Chart from "react-google-charts";


function Tables(props) {

  useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(props);
  },[])  


  return (<Container className="mt-5">
    <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>State/UT</th>
      <th>Infected</th>
      <th>Recovered</th>
      <th>Death</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {/* {
        this.props.data["statewise"].map((item)=>{
        return <>
        <tr>
      <td>{item["state"]}</td>
      <td>{item["confirmed"]}</td>
      <td>{item["recovered"]}</td>
      <td>{item["deaths"]}</td>
    </tr>
        </>    
        })
    } */}
    <tr>
      <td>MAHARASHTRA</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KERALA</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>UTTAR PRADESH</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DELHI</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</Table>
  </Container>);
}

export default Tables;
```

Please Help Me out!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a loose equality check(`==`) to conditionally render the data. By doing so if the data was `null` or `undefined` it would still render the true case which is the loader in this case. If the data has not been set and you try to use the value from `set_data` it will return undefined.

```
null == null
// returns true
```

```
undefined == null
// returns true
```

Instead you can do the following where if the data is has not been set then you render the loader otherwise you render the table with the JSON data from the API.

```
!state_data ? (
    <Container id="load">
      <center>
        <Spinner animation="grow" variant="dark" size="100" />
     </center>
    </Container> ) : ( 
    <div>
      <Tables data={JSON.stringify(state_data)} />
   </div> )
```

Or the other way around where if the data has been set then render the data in a table form otherwise render the loader

```
state_data ? (
    <div>
      <Tables data={JSON.stringify(state_data)} />
   </div> ) : (
  <Container id="load">
      <center>
        <Spinner animation="grow" variant="dark" size="100" />
     </center>
  </Container>
```